# CGAL Delaunay triangulation, removal of a point

Tags: 2d, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

Simple question: How to remove a point in a a 2d delaunay triangulation if I have only the coordinates of the point, I´m sure the point was inserted before. CDT::remove requires vertex_handle as a parameter but I don´t have it.

Thanks in advance;

Comment: "Locate" the point to get a vertex handle?

Comment: I tried this but in Locate I get the Face_handle not the vertex_handle.

Comment: Did you look at all the overloads of `locate`? One of them also tells you which vertex of this face it is. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__2.html#af61a05a0a53d009e111a3873c1796b52

Answer (score 2):

That is a loss that you no longer have the `Vertex_handle`, because you will have to recompute the location of the point. The simplest way is to insert it again: the insertion of point that already exists as a vertex of the triangulation will return the `Vertex_handle` of the existing vertex.

So, in short, my answer is:

```cpp
    tr.remove(tr.insert(point));
```

Comment: thasnk you Irineu!  Would be great if we could remove a point having only the coordinates, happens allways :)

Comment: @Rabelo That function will never be added to CGAL, because it is inefficient. We only provide functions and methods that are known to be efficient. The answer I gave you `tr.remove(tr.insert(point));` is the fastest way to remove a point using its coordinates, and at the same time it shows you that it is doing something twice. If you care about efficiency, you should store in a map the association between points and vertex handles, so that you can remove vertices efficiently.

Comment: That was my concern: eficiency because I will have to insert to then remove. But  as you said on GCAL it will be inefficient, ok. I think that at the end this ineficiency problem will get on users programs because that ineficient way is the only way of doing that. I agree that  you have to conserve the  eficiency of CGAL.