# Why thisexcleption is being raised on Constrained Delaunay Triangulation and Gabriel Triangulations?

Tags: cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I´m working on a triangulation that can be set as constrained Delaunay Triangulation or a Gabriel Triangulation. When I set it as a constrained Delaunay Triangulation all work fine but when I set it as a conforming Delaunay or conforming Gabriel an exception inside CGAL is raised. The text of de exception is:

```
CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!\nExpr: n == zone.fh\nFile: C:\\dev\\CGAL-5.3.1\\include\\CGAL\\Mesh_2\\Refine_edges.h\nLine: 429"
```

It happens when I call  `CGAL::make_conforming_Delaunay_2(cdt);`  or `CGAL::make_conforming_Gabriel_2(cdt);`

on file refine_edges.h:

```
Zone conflicts_zone_impl(const Point& p, Edge edge)
  {
    Zone zone;

    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<typename Zone::Faces> OutputItFaces;
    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<typename Zone::Edges> OutputItEdges;

    OutputItFaces faces_out(zone.faces);
    OutputItEdges edges_out(zone.boundary_edges);

    const Face_handle& f = edge.first;
    const int i = edge.second;

    zone.fh = triangulation_ref_impl().locate(p, zone.locate_type, zone.i, edge.first);

    const Face_handle n = f->neighbor(i);

    const bool f_does_conflict = (zone.locate_type == Tr::EDGE) ||
      triangulation_ref_impl().test_conflict(p, f);

    if(f_does_conflict) {
       *faces_out++ = f;
    } else {
      CGAL_assertion(n == zone.fh);      <<============== Line 429
    }

    const bool n_does_conflict = (zone.locate_type == Tr::EDGE) ||
      triangulation_ref_impl().test_conflict(p, n);

    CGAL_assertion(f_does_conflict ||
                   n_does_conflict);
```

Why is this exception being raised?

Thank you

Comment: What is you triangulation type?

Comment: That is highly improbable that your issue is a CGAL bug. Your code and inputs probably violate a precondition of the functions you are using.

Same as with the previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71180040/1728537): if you share your code and data set, then you can have better answers. See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: The funny is that if I don´t call CGAL::make_conforming_Delaunay_2(cdt);  or CGAL::make_conforming_Gabriel_2(cdt); all works fine.  Based on the message on the exception I cant have a clue of what is happening. The code is a litle tricy but I will send you a dump of the triangulation just before I call them. Thank you very much.