# Why CDT cannot read a file created by itself?

Tags: cgal, triangulation, delaunay

this question is a continuing of  [Error on Constrained Delaunay Triangulation and Gabriel Triangulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321126/error-on-constrained-delaunay-triangulation-and-gabriel-triangulations)

Trying to write a minimal example for that problem I planned insert the triangulation
in a file (std::ofstream) using the << operator of CDT without calling the  `CGAL::make_conforming_Delaunay_2(cdt);` or `CGAL::make_conforming_Gabriel_2(cdt)`,
knowing that until this point everything occured OK.
The triangulation was created without problems and before the exit of the aplication I saved the triangulation in a file using the << operator of CDT. The file was saved without error.
When I tried to read the file using the >> operator of CDT an exception was raised (inside the >> operator). The text of exception is:

```
CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!\nExpr: s == LEFT_TURN\nFile: C:\\dev\\CGAL-5.3.1\\include\\CGAL\\Triangulation_2.h\nLine: 919
```

The code I wrote:

```
int main()
{    
      CDT cdt;
    
      std::ifstream ArqSuperficie("trian.dtr");  This file was created with << operator of CDT
    
      if (ArqSuperficie.good() == false)
      {
        return 1;
      }
    
      try()
      {
        ArqSuperficie >> cdt;      
      }
      catch(std::exception& e)
      {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: exception " << e.what() << std::endl; 
      }
    
      return 0;
    }
```

Why CDT cannot read a file created by itself, of a triangulation that was created by itself without errors?

Based on the message of the exception I can´t have a clue of what is happening...

Thank you